# Is there any way to start consuming kafka topics from a specific offset in Java API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Stream API. When I start my application sometimes there is a gap and I want to start consuming from a specific offset. Earliest or latest is not what I want.

```java
streamProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

What I'm looking for is a scenario like I set offset number or a date in milliseconds in config file and start consuming from that point onward. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you investigate where the gap comes from? "Latest" should provide you with the last offset that hasn't been consumed before, so there shouldn't be one.

Comment: Good point. But the thing that happens is my application is down for more than the topic retention is set. So the offset is no more valid. I thought earliest will start from the earliest offset available (hence the name) but when I set it to earliest it set the offset to INITIAL and threw an exception

Comment: If you're not limited to kafka and can switch to pulsar, pulsar can do it https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-java/#sticky-key-range-reader

Comment: @agilob looking good but it would be a huge migration

Comment: Then maybe check if pulsar client with kafka compatibility mode supports it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config `auto.offset.reset` is only effective for the first start of your application when no offset are committed yet. If offsets are committed, the application will always resume processing from the committed offsets.

In Kafka Streams, there is no API to set start offsets explicitly. The consumer API would allow this via `Consumer#seek()`.

For Kafka Streams, one way to get the behavior you want is, to stop the application, use `bin/kafka-consmer.group.sh` (or maybe better `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh`), and commit the desired start offset. If you start the application afterwards, it will pick up the committed offset and start processing from there.